# SOLR 6.5.1 will not run with Sitecore as a service on Windows machine

Tags: solr

Got SOLR setup and working on my local machine with all my cores installed. Everything is functioning as intended when starting SOLR from Command Prompt via a "bin\solr start" command. However, I installed SOLR as a service via NSSM and while the service was created and is in place, the service will not start for some reason. The error I am getting back is as follows when I attempt to start the service:

> Windows could not start the SOLR 6.5.1 service on Local Computer. The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error. If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.

These are the steps that I followed when setting up Sitecore 8.2 (Update 3) with SOLR (6.5.1): https://www.norconex.com/how-to-run-solr5-as-a-service-on-windows/

I made sure that I have the JAVA_HOME environment variable in place with the correct path as variable, and I am using 64 bit version of JAVA while using the 64 bit version of NSSM as well when creating the service. Any help is appreciated to solve this issue!

Comment: Do you have different Java versions on your machine?

Comment: No. I only have Java 8 Update 131 (64-bit) installed.

Comment: I've just updated my `JRE` to 131 and did get the error specified. I fixed it by changing the `System Variable` for `JAVA_HOME` from Environment Variable to the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131` and it started running. Can you share a screenshot of your environment variables and directories of the JRE if the issue still persist

Comment: Java directory is same as yours. System variable is "JAVA_HOME" and value is "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131". Are there any other settings I am missing in Environment Variables dialog box?

Comment: Just for a test, can you make use of SOLR v6.2.1 and see if it works. I am not sure, but it seems I had once heard of the version compatibility.

Comment: Just adding 2 cents. I use Bitnami installer for SOLR. It installs all you need to run SOLR, one simple install. Installs it as a service for you. https://bitnami.com/stack/solr/installer

Comment: Check Solr logs files and check EventViewer for errors in starting the Service?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not related to Sitecore, is related to SOLR

Comment: My vote is to keep it open. SOLR is core to Sitecore and others will be looking for the answer to this question, when setting up SOLR with Sitecore.

Comment: Tried 6.2.1 and same message. Tried Bitnami 6.6.0 and didn't work to get service setup. Nothing detailed in the Event Viewer either. I am going to just run this as non-service for now.

Comment: The issue of services failing to start is mentioned on NSSM homepage:
2017-04-26: Users of Windows 10 Creators Update should use prelease build 2.2.4-101 to avoid an issue with services failing to start.

I wonder if you tried that prerelease build: https://nssm.cc/ci/nssm-2.24-101-g897c7ad.zip

Comment: @TobyGutierrez did you check if you don't have any other Solr running on the same machine? It might be a port conflict that are not allowing you to start as Windows service neither using Bitnami! Run "netstat -nao" and see if is there any 8983 already listening.

Comment: Good point @Vinicius Deschamps. Or just try a completely different port.

Comment: @grg the pre-release build was the answer. Please answer I will mark that as the answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: It's great that you made it work!

Comment: I agree with @TobyGutierrez Solr is now even more core to Sitecore with the release of 9 and it being the default Search Provider.

Comment: I'm trying to install SC 9 and it won't work without Solr 6 so I'd say this is directly related to Sitecore!

Comment: I also recently faced this problem in my laptop. What is interesting earlier - that stuff was working, I seems to be changed nothing (well windows updates were installed and probably Java was updated to some newer build on 1.8). I think this question should be opened again.

Comment: Well, after some investigation, I figured out that my JAVA_HOME variable was pointing to the non-existing folder. I believe, during update of the Java, it was removed and new folder named after Java version and revision number has been created, therefore inmy case that was a Java issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue of services failing to start is mentioned on NSSM homepage: Users of Windows 10 Creators Update should use [prerelease build 2.2.4-101](http://nssm.cc/ci/nssm-2.24-101-g897c7ad.zip) to avoid an issue with services failing to start.

Comment: I've tried using this release but still getting the service failed to start error. any alternative fixes to this?

Comment: That doesn't work for me either

Comment: For me, the problem was Java was updated to a new version, and the old version was removed. So the JAVA_HOME Windows environment variable was pointing to a path that no longer existed. Updating the variable to the new path fixed the issue.

Comment: I had similar issues. I realized I had a 32 bit jre installed, but had installed solr using 64 bit nssm. I installed via 32 bit nssm (the pre-release build still) and it worked.

Comment: Troubleshooting steps that were helpful for me:
1) checking that the JAVA_HOME variable was available in a PS prompt: echo $env:JAVA_HOME
2) Installing an older version of Java, in this case, 9.0.1